# Tomcat URL mapping using jersey

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I'm having some trouble in URL mapping for a Jersey/Tomcat application.

Here is my mapping:

URL mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller

```
@Path("/file")
public class FileUploadService {
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
```

Form

```
<form action="rest/file/upload" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

When I click the form the corresponding controller `localhost:8080/appname/rest/file/upload` is called but when I change the URL mapping to below.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and form

```
<form action="file/upload" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

`localhost:8080/appname/file/upload` gives me a 404 page.

Comment: `/*/*` is wrong, if you need to listen to all address, use `/*` for all address.

Comment: Have you tried just '/*' in the second url pattern? I believe that /*/* will match the file/upload action in your new form and will direct to the controller. Once it reaches the controller though, it has cannot find a path method in the class.